# IOS: StoreKit API usage in reader apps with external link to website

Tags: ios, storekit

According to this [document from Apple](https://developer.apple.com/support/reader-apps/#:%7E:text=The%20External%20Link%20Account%20Entitlement%20is%20optional%20and%20only%20required,the%20app%2C%20per%20guideline%203.1) it requires to call `canMakePayments` API before displaying external link alert UI to confirm that the user has permission to make payments.

It is not clear what app should do depending on the response of `canMakePayments` function. Should an alert be displayed in both cases? And what is the purpose of calling that function?

Comment: The document seems quite clear. If `canMakePayments' returns `false` then you do not display the external link alert and do not open your web site. You may choose to show an alert informing th user that purchases are not permitted on their device. The purpose of calling the function is to check restrictions, such as parental controls, that may be in effect on the device

Answer (score 0):

> Should an alert be displayed in both cases?

No, an alert should only be displayed when the user does not have permission to make payments, i.e. `canMakePayments` is false.

> And what is the purpose of calling that function?

The purpose of calling that function is to not show the in-app modal sheet for users who do not have permission to make payments, so to only show the modal for users when `canMakePayments` is true.